# How to work with checkBoxes when they are input parameters?

Tags: c#

My checkBoxes must be input parameters, events are not solution(I know how to work with events).

My wf looks like this:

[image]

Sorry, it is not in english language, but never mind, I will explain. I have four checkboxes in this first group box("Način unosa" : "Kraj dana" is checkBox1, "Pozadinski unos" is checkBox2, "Dopuna" is checkBox3, "Odloženi online" is checkBox4). When I click on button Pretraga(it is search button), I have some rows which is ok, but I don`t know how to type code about checkboxes.

I know how it can work with only two checkBoxex,

```
private void btnPretraga_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some code before checkBoxes

    string nacinUnosa;//this is input parameter

    if((checkBox1.Checked = true) && (checkBox2.Checked = true))
    {
        nacinUnosa = "%":
    }
    if((checkBox1.Checked = true) && (checkBox2.Checked = false))
    {
        nacinUnosa = "1"
    }
    if((checkBox1.Checked = false) && (checkBox2.Checked = true))
    {
        nacinUnosa = "2"
    }
    //and so on...
}
```

but I don't know how is this working with four chechBoxex... There must be another way. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any information about what should be done according to the checkboxes are checked or not,

Comment: By the way instead of `if(CheckBox1.Checked == true)` you can just say `if(CheckBox1.Checked)`. Also instead of `if(CheckBox1.Checked == false)` you can say `if(!CheckBox1.Checked)`

Comment: and for `if(CheckBox1.Checked == false)` you can say `if(!CheckBox1.Checked)`- just as addition what Alfie said.

Comment: Ok, it is cleaner code, tnx for advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to this is to split them into different sections for each box like this:

```
if(checkBox1.Checked)
{
    if(checkBox2.Checked)
    {
        nacinUnosa = "%";
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
//And so on
```

If you wish to reduce the size of the if statements without splitting them like this you could also use single line if statements such as

```
nacinUnosa = (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked) ? "%" : checkBox1.Checked ? "1" : checkBox2.Checked ? "2" : "0";
```

A benefit of this is that you can still set it out nicely by splitting it to make it **look** like it is a multiline statement. As such, this is the exact same code with better formatting

```
nacinUnosa = 
(checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked) 
? "%" 
: checkBox1.Checked 
? "1" 
: checkBox2.Checked 
? "2" 
: "0";
```

**The full code**

```
nacinUnosa = 
(checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked && checkBox4.Checked) 
? "%" 
: (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked) 
? "123" 
: (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked && checkBox4.Checked) 
? "124" 
: (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox3.Checked && checkBox4.Checked) 
? "134" 
: (checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked && checkBox4.Checked) 
? "234" 
: (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked) 
? "12" 
: (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox3.Checked) 
? "13" 
: (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox4.Checked) 
? "14" 
: (checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked) 
? "23" 
: (checkBox2.Checked && checkBox4.Checked) 
? "24" 
: (checkBox3.Checked && checkBox4.Checked) 
? "34" 
: (checkBox1.Checked) 
? "1" 
: (checkBox2.Checked) 
? "2" 
: (checkBox3.Checked) 
? "3" 
: (checkBox4.Checked) 
? "4" 
: "0";
```

**How to work this out in future**

You can work this out in future by using combinatorics, this allows you to know how many possibilities there are in each set, when you have 4 checkBoxes checked, the possibilities are just 4C4, which is equal to 1. As you move on it becomes 4C3 (which is equal to 4), 4C2 (which is 6) and 4C1, which is 4. As a result, there should be 15 outcomes, as well as one extra for when none are ticked at all!

Comment: `nacinUnosa = 
(checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked && checkBox4.Checked) 
? "%" 
: checkBox1.Checked 
? "1" 
: checkBox2.Checked 
? "2" 
: checkBox3.Checked 
? "3" 
: checkBox4.Checked 
? "4" 
: "0";`

This will not work. Dont know why... Because when I check box2 and box3 it will only show rows which have "nacinUnosa" value 2(not value 2 and value 3)...

Comment: That would not be correct, as in your code it is never checked if both 1 and 2 (or both 3 and 4 or 2 and 4 etc.) are ticked, which means that if you ticked boxes 1,3 and 4, the result would just be "1". You are also not checking if 4 is checked at all aside from at the beginning

Comment: I will edit the code that should be used into my answer, as it may be too long to fit in a comment

Comment: I am sorry if I was incomprehensible. I see that you understand me now. Tnx a lot.

Comment: I hope this is helpful, please mark as the answer if it solved your issue :)

Comment: It is not working... again... When I turn on debuger and go line by line, i see that string nacinUnosa have value "1, 2" (if I checked first and second check box)... And probably the program cant recognize that this are two values, it see this like one value which is not exist... Maybe I should put "1" + "2" instead of "1, 2" or something like "1" and "2"... I dont know...

Comment: What do you want it to return in the nacinUnosa field? For example if the checked boxes are 1 and 2, should it return "1,2" or "1 and 2" or "1 & 2" or "1 + 2"? or even "12" or "3"

Comment: If the checked boxes are 1 or 2, I want it to return all rows from ORACLE database which have nacinUnosa 1 or 2... I dont know how should be in C#, how should nacinUnosa field understand that 1 and 2 are two values which I want to return. Understand? In your code you type "1, 2", but it is not working, my proposition is that maybe "1" + "2" will work... I am trying now every possibility... It should return "1" and "2", not "1,2"...

Comment: If it is being put directly into the oracle SQL, the SQL would most likely read `WHERE nacinUnosa = 1,2` at this point, which would not work, this should be changed into "1 AND nacinUnosa = 2" (This might be way off)

Comment: It is easier to type "123" instead of "1, 2, 3". Please, edit it. I marked your answer as solved.:) It is easier because of procedure in ORACLE, I answered to my own question how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You want to check the checkedstatus on all of the checkboxes?

First of all I think you need to use 2 `=`'s in the if statement

```
if(checkBox1.Checked == true)
```

I think the only way is to make bigger `if`s

I also think an if/else structure isn't a bad idea in this case.

like this:

```
if(checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked && checkBox4.Checked) 
{
}
else if(!checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked && checkBox3.Checked && checkBox4.Checked) 
{
}
...
```

And go over this for all the posibilities (it are alot of them, true)

Comment: Yeah, ==, sorry. I know, it have to be bigger if, but alot of posibilities... So, you think that I have to type all posibilities? Any easier way?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't another way. I hope there is and I'm going to follow your question to look at other answers. I'm also a "new" programmer imo.

Comment: Haha, ok, we will look at other answers together...:) If there is no other way, then I will type this... Tnx anyway.

Comment: Also a good idea is that if this is being done multiple times you can put in a method and just specify the boxes

Comment: My guess is that he only needs to know their status when he presses the _search_ button. Otherwise you are right. Everything that needs to be used more then once from different places should be in a separate method and only written once. (good practice)

Answer (score 1):

What you try to achieve can be easily done with flags or arrays.

I did read your comments on [Alfie Goodacre his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36329737/4632401), and you can keep it at lot simpler than that:

```
//Instead of storing it in a string, we use a list of strings
nacinUnosa = List<string>();

//Just check each checkbox once...
if (checkBox1.Checked)
    nacinUnosa.push("1");
if (checkBox2.Checked)
    nacinUnosa.push("2");
if (checkBox3.Checked)
    nacinUnosa.push("3");
if (checkBox4.Checked)
    nacinUnosa.push("4");

//Now we have a full list with all the active checkboxes.. For the query, we can do something like:
var query = "SELECT * FROM Clothes WHERE ";
for (var i = 0; i < nacinUnosa.length; i++) {
    //Create your sql query code here.. Something like:
    if (i != 0) 
       query += " OR " ;

    nacinUnosa = " + nacinUnosa[i] " ;
}
```

Comment: Nice and correct answer... Query can work like this:

Answer (score 0):

All of your answers are correct. Another way:

```
string nacinUnosa = "";

if (checkBox1.Checked) nacinUnosa = "1";
if (checkBox2.Checked) nacinUnosa = nacinUnosa + "2";
if (checkBox3.Checked) nacinUnosa = nacinUnosa + "3";
if (checkBox4.Checked) nacinUnosa = nacinUnosa + "4";
```

Query can work like this:

```
SELECT d.nacin_unosa, ....//nacin_unosa is column in table
FROM DNEVNIK d, ... //DNEVNIK is table
WHERE P_NACIN_UNOSA like ('%'||d.nacin_unosa||'%') // P_NACIN_UNOSA is input parameter
```

Thank you for you answers...:)